# Loading required namespace: pbkrtest Failed with error: 'there is no package called 'pbkrtest''

Tags: r, package, package-development, emmeans

After using [emmeans](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html) `R` package in my package I started getting the following error:

> Loading required namespace: pbkrtest
>
> Failed with error:  'there is no package called 'pbkrtest''

during `devtools::check_win_devel()`. Wonder what is the remedy here.

Comment: Sounds like the maintainer of `pbkrtest` would have to do some work to get his package compatible with R-devel?

Comment: I think you just need to install the package pbkrtest